# Is there any theoretical way (general rules) to find out, which script is optimal and will load faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

If there are two or more ways to write scripts, that will do the same thing is there any theoretical way (general rules) to find out, which script is optimal and will load faster?

Comment: Sure, run a performance test

Comment: Tools like https://jsperf.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Big O** provides the upper bounds in time space complexity.

**Big Omega** provides lower bounds.

**Big Theta** provides a combination of the first two with tight bounds.

What you get from these notations are the expectations of how a algorithm will perform and from this you could compare two different algorithms in their complexity and choose the ideal bounds for your needs. All depends on how you want to define performance.

If you’d like to learn more I suggest looking into data structures and algorithms. That should give you a good understanding in what all this Big O stuff is about.

If you’d like more detail on resources just message me!

Answer (score 1):

No it can't be done theoretically, that is why people run benchmarks and do profiling of their code.

You can theoretically work out the complexity of your algorithm, for example your script may be O(n^2) by number of files. (That's called big O notation), but that won't tell you the real-world performance.